# Check whether error is due to connection being closed

Tags: networking, go, connection

Is there a way in Go to check whether an error returned from a network operation (e.g., `net.Conn`'s various methods) is due to the connection having been manually closed locally (via a `Close` method)? In particular, I'm *not* talking about `io.EOF`, which implies that the other side of the connection closed it.

Comment: See https://golang.org/issue/4373 -- while it seems useful at first, when you analyze it there is rarely a case where it's useful _and_ you don't know yourself that you're closing the connection.

Comment: Unfortunately I am in one of those rare cases. But thanks!

Comment: To clarify: I can implement something else that effects the "was I the one who closed the connection?" check, but it's much more complicated than just getting it from the error.

Comment: Yeah, you kind of have to plan ahead if you need to signal for that, otherwise you're left parsing the error string. Things to think about, does the error actually matter, or are you just trying to format a log message (or similar)? Can you catch the error from a Read, and shutdown the read half of the connection first, which returns a clean io.EOF?

Comment: It's one of those things where you have a separate goroutine for reading and writing each, and need the two to be able to communicate in the event of an error. I'm currently using a sync.Once to make sure that only the first error is logged. The code, if you're curious: https://github.com/joshlf/gokeyless/blob/adbdfd1931924d760d8d5c326c5bcf869c07227a/server/server.go#L465

Comment: Why not just add a `wasClosed bool` to your struct?

Comment: That's what the `sync.Once` provides. Plus, `wasClosed bool` would require some other synchronization (mutex, etc). With `sync.Once`, we get it for free.